# Flutter build appbundle not creating 64bit and adding unnecessary permission?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

Hi i build app and upload to google play console.
i got this error !

> Error Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the
>   following permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA. Apps using these
>   permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

but acctually i dont use camera or camera permission. in AndroidManifest.xml also just **android.permission.INTERNET**

then i read from flutter website that flutter build appbundle will compiled for armeabi-v7a (32-bit) and arm64-v8a (64-bit).

but i got this warning on play console

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 1.

please help me with this 2 problem :(

flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.207], locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (2 months ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\KLIK-EAT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 36.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.36.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\KLIK-EAT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party libraries ? If so, can you post them here. ?

Comment: ya use 3rd library
-flare_flutter
-rxdart
-shimmer
-flutter_swiper
-flutter_cache_manager
-cached_network_image
-sqflite
-flutter_html
-intl
badges: ^0.0.6
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.2.4
  google_maps_flutter:  0.0.3+3
  photo_view: ^0.4.0
  rounded_modal: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: 4.1.0+1
  cupertino_range_slider: ^1.0.1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
  package_info: 0.3.2+1
  easy_listview: ^0.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks already fixed
 1. for camera uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove"
 2. for 64bit bundle, i update to latest flutter stabil and it build 64.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing for "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" but I'm getting error
* What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig'.
[        ] > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/apple/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 100; The prefix "tools"
for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.